# Program not running under GDB

Tags: gcc, gdb

I need to examine a sample code under GDB with cc1 of GCC loaded in GDB. I have built GCC under debugging using :

```
make STAGE1_CXXFLAGS="-g3"
```

and invoking cc1 in GDB using gdb --args cc1 which says successfully loaded gdb hooks for cc1. When running a program : run > foo.c , the processing hangs on saying : Starting program /path_to_program/foo.c and nothing happens. What could be going wrong?

Comment: You are running a debugger. Might just as well use it to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> nothing happens

You didn't give `cc1` any arguments (input file in particular), so it waits for `stdin` instead.

> run > foo.c

You probably meant `run foo.c` (*without* redirection). You could also do:

```
gdb --args cc1 foo.c
(gdb) run
```

Comment: Oh! I thought > is used for input file. My fault. Thanks, it worked.

Comment: @TejasJoshi The `>` *is* used to redirect `stdout` of a program into a file. But here you don't care about `cc1`s `stdout` and you want to give it *input*, not output.